# Auto-pick turn based match behaving strangely

Tags: android-studio, google-play-games, multiplayer

I have implemented android quiz app with turnbased multiplayer games. Strange behaviour is when player1 creats an auto-pick match and plays, this game is never sent to other player i.e player2 as i have only 2 devices for testing. Now I can see game is waiting for opponent which is never reached to player2. Now I send an autopick match from player2 and this match is sent to player1 by replacing player1's sent match and it becomes my turn at player1 and he can play it normally. How to resolve this issue?

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);
    dismissSpinner();
   if (request == RC_LOOK_AT_MATCHES) {
        // Returning from the 'Select Match' dialog
        if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // user canceled
            return;
        }
        TurnBasedMatch match = data
                .getParcelableExtra(Multiplayer.EXTRA_TURN_BASED_MATCH);

        if (match != null) {
            //update match here
            updateMatch(match); //Pls ignore this nothing happen here, still under development
        } else {
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "finish", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if (request == RC_SELECT_PLAYERS) {
        // Returned from 'Select players to Invite' dialog
        if (response != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // user canceled
        }
        else{
            startNewMatchWithIntent(data);
        }

    }
}

private void startNewMatchWithIntent(Intent intent)
{
    //    Log.d("activityResult", "ResultOK");
    // get the invitee list
    final ArrayList<String> invitees = intent
            .getStringArrayListExtra(Games.EXTRA_PLAYER_IDS);
    // get automatch criteria
    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = null;

    int minAutoMatchPlayers = intent.getIntExtra(
            Multiplayer.EXTRA_MIN_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);
    int maxAutoMatchPlayers = intent.getIntExtra(
            Multiplayer.EXTRA_MAX_AUTOMATCH_PLAYERS, 0);


    if (minAutoMatchPlayers > 0) {
        autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(
                minAutoMatchPlayers, maxAutoMatchPlayers, 0);
    } else {
        autoMatchCriteria = null;
    }


    TurnBasedMatchConfig tbmc = TurnBasedMatchConfig.builder()
            .addInvitedPlayers(invitees)
            .setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria).build();

    // Start the match
    Games.TurnBasedMultiplayer.createMatch(mGoogleApiClient, tbmc).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull TurnBasedMultiplayer.InitiateMatchResult result) {
                    dismissSpinner();
                    processResult(result);
                    Log.d(TAG, "create match :" + String.valueOf(result.getMatch().getDescriptionParticipant()));
                }
            });
    showSpinner();
}
```

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question without seeing any code. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: added code blocks. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done so, you may want to first visit [Adding Turn-based Multiplayer Support to Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/turnbasedMultiplayer) wherein it was suggested to also review [turn-based multiplayer game concepts](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/turnbasedMultiplayer).

As enumerated, before you start to code your turn-based multiplayer game:

> - Make sure to [enable turn-based multiplayer support](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/configuring#enabling_multiplayer_support) for your game in the Google Play Developer Console.
> - Download and review the turn-based multiplayer game code samples in the [Android samples page](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples).
> - Familiarize yourself with the recommendations described in [Quality Checklist](https://developers.google.com/games/services/checklist).
>
> Once the player is signed in and the [GoogleApiClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient) is connected, your game can start using the turn-based multiplayer API.